# NVidia graphics driver cannot detect second monitor

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg, multiple-monitors

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my ThinkPad W520 with a NVidia Quadro 1000M graphics card. I then switched over to a NVidia proprietary driver. However, when I plugged in my second monitor through a VGA cable, it simply does not show up. Ubuntu can not find it and `xrandr` shows that VGA1 is disconnected. NVidia X Server Settings also doesn't show anything.

[NVidia X Server Settings image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AAeVh.png)

Thanks in advance

Note: Switching to a non-propriety driver like X.org works, but the second screen glitches out. The laptop monitor is just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally it is recommended to use the NVIDIA drivers 352 from the official Ubuntu repositories.
But when there are problems with these drivers, you can install the latest official NVIDIA drivers.
This often leads to properly working graphics, a few days ago NVIDIA released stable drivers 361.

Remove the currently installed drivers.
Open a terminal and execute :

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*  
sudo reboot
```

Install the latest official stable drivers.
Open a terminal and execute :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-361 nvidia-prime
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Sadly, I'm back on a VM again. Hopefully, this can be helpful to those looking as well as for my future reference.